# Top right menu using Vuetify.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've just started to learn vue. I want to create a horizontal top-right menu using Vuetify.

But I've jot vertical menu instead. There are not such examples on Vuetify documentation. There is no exact implementation of the most used menu. How can I configure it to make it horizontal?
Here is template

```
<v-app>
  <v-app-bar
    app
    color="primary"
    light
  >
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      right
      width="500"
    >
      <v-list
        nav
        dense
        max-width="240"
      >
        <v-list-item-group>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-title>Log in</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-title>Sign in</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-spacer />
  </v-app-bar>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a bar with  some items aligned horizontally in the right side you could do it simply like :

```
<v-app-bar color="deep-purple accent-4" dense dark>

        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <v-btn text>
          Log in
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn text>
          Sign in
        </v-btn>
</v-app-bar>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/zYBXWBG)